# Best way to avoid DPI/tunnel detection?

Tags: vpn, tunneling, vps, dpi, openwrt

guys, I live in Russia and that pretty much says it all.

I was using a standard self-hosted VPN on a DO droplet, but now I'm afraid that since VPN usage in Russia started to spread like a wildfire after the recent Instagram ban the Russian government will surely try to restrict the usage of any kinds of VPN (and they have the tools).

The way I see it, I need to obfuscate my traffic as much as I can, make everything look like standard HTTPS exchanges or something. But I'm by no means a network pro and I need some guidance on whether there are readymade trusted solutions for that.

I would love to set up a secure channel between my OpenWRT router (Meraki, a capable machine, don't need Pi for that), and a VPS. How do I start to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: *"make everything look like standard HTTPS exchanges or something."* - no matter how you obfuscate the application protocol it will still be obvious for an observer that all traffic from your home is to a single other system,  which means this approach will never look like real HTTPS where communication is done with lots of different systems.  That said, have a look at [obfsproxy](https://www.sparklabs.com/support/kb/article/setting-up-an-obfuscation-server-with-obfsproxy-and-viscosity/) or [tunnel wireguard over websocket](https://github.com/jnsgruk/wireguard-over-wss).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich's response is probably as good as you'll get, and while that's likely your best bet, it comes with some serious risks given a sophisticated adversary like Russia. Some projects tried and failed to accomplish a secure way to hide in the noise, such as [Haystack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haystack_%28software%29) in 2010. Steffen, why not make that an answer?

Comment: Thank you, guys. Appreciate the help. Will take it from here.

Comment: This news item may be of interest to you: [Meet the Secretive US Company Building an 'Unbreakable' Internet Inside Russia](https://www.vice.com/en/article/z3n5e9/russian-internet-lantern).